# How to check whether the richface pop up panel is visible or not

Tags: javascript, html, richfaces, richfaces-modal

In following code: **code1** onClick function opensUp a RichFace popup panel. i need the onComplete fuction to execute after the closing of the popup. how can i delay the onComplete function. Is there a way to check whether the popup is visible or not as shown in the **code2** so that this execution is delayed.

The code1:
`<a  onclick ="showPopup('popup1')" oncomplete="" > Input </a>`

The code2:
`<a  onclick ="showPopup('popup1');  while(isVisible('popup1')){ }"`
`oncomplete="" > Input </a>`

Comment: Why don't you use `onhide`?

Comment: I am very new to RichFaces. how to use onhide? Is it like this  `<a onclick=" "  oncomplete=" onhide('popup')  { } " >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `onhide` attribute from `rich:popupPanel`. The description of it is: *The client-side code executed after the popup disappears*.

```
<h:commandButton value="Call the popup">
    <rich:componentControl target="popup" operation="show" />
</h:commandButton>

<rich:popupPanel id="popup" modal="true"
    onhide="alert('My popup is now hidden!')"
    onshow="alert('This popup just pop out!');">
    <!-- (... some body ...) -->
</rich:popupPanel>
```

If you really want to check in JavaScript if the popup is hidden or visible, then use `RichFaces` object in JavaScript, find popup and check `shown` field. An example:

```
if (RichFaces.$('MyPopupId').shown) {alert('Shown')} else {alert('Hidden')}
```

Check [RichFaces VDL](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/vdldoc/index.html?rich/popupPanel.html) for more info.